# Django - Authentication using REMOTE_USER - How to test in dev server?

Tags: python, django, debugging, authentication

I want to use django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware for authentication as outlined here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/

Question is, how can I test this in a dev environment where there is no Apache? i.e. can I set REMOTE_USER somehow in local settings?

**EDIT** (adding settings)

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    ...
)
```

Then I have this in my local_Settings:

```
os.environ['REMOTE_USER'] = "mmatyas"
```

I also tried the 'HTTP_REMOTE_USER' variant. Thanks!

Comment: It’s a pretty old question now, but have you found an answer since then? I’m also struggling with this right now.

Comment: I did not. However I ended up switching my auth mechanism. Instead of doing at Apache level I'm doing at Django level. So I'm using `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` during development and in production `django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend`

Answer (score 1):

The variable has to be set in the environment in which you start the dev server. usually it's just:

```
REMOTE_USER=myuser ./manage.py runserver
```

Comment: This doesn't test basic auth. This hardcodes the login, which is the opposite of testing the login. Setting `REMOTE_USER` ignores the password passed.

Comment: @Cerin, this sets REMOTE_USER so they can see how the middleware and auth backends handle it, which is exactly what they're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can write some WSGI middleware and set it there, and then make sure the wsgi middleware wraps your django app in the wsgi stack. lots of tutorials around on writing wsgi middleware, it'll be a short one page of code. Easy-peasy-lemon-squeezy!

Answer (score -1):

In your dev environment, you can set an environment variable in the same command prompt you use to start up your dev server.

Something like `export REMOTE_USER="duncan"` if on a Unixy machine.

You can also do this by editing your manage.py and setting `os.environ['REMOTE_USER'] = "duncan"`

Comment: Hi Jordan, none of these methods seem to work for me. Not sure if I'm missing something. I can see that I'm setting os.environ['REMOTE_USER'] cuz I can log it from a view later. However request.META['REMOTE_USER'] is not getting set, and I think this is why the authentication isn't happening. I'll Edit my question with the relevant settings info - maybe I'm doing something wrong. thanks

Comment: FWIW, I was able to get this to work with Apache and using SetEnv REMOTE_USER "mmatyas". Still would be nice to get it to work without Apache for development purposes...

Comment: Adding `os.environ['REMOTE_USER'] = "duncan"` to manage.py will not set `request.META['REMOTE_USER']`